# Connection to MariaDB 10.1.23 on Debian 9 (Stretch) from LAN

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb, stretch

I've just set up debian 9 server with MariaDB server (which is the default flavor of MySQL from releasing Stretch).

Unfortunately, I'cant figure it out how to connect to MariaDB from any LAN machine.

There is no anything in my.cnf (bind-address or skip-networking). I've opened 3306 in iptables.

It seems that is MariaDB configured to listen only on localhost, but I don't know how/where to change this.

Answer (score 4):

bind-address is set in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

```
$ grep -r bind.address /etc/m*
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you! I've searched half a day for this!